# Как изменить размер JButton в Java

Tags: java, javafx, java-ee

что делать? Я попробовал все методы/ или же большую часть... 
Нечего не получается...
Кто поможет?

Comment: в каком она лежит layout-е?

Comment: это андроид? @StrangerintheQ

Comment: Нет,не андроид  обычная приложение

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой метод это сделать так:

```
JButton button = new JButton('Test button');
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
```

Comment: Чекал не роботает

Comment: e вас андроид или se?